# Transforming variable to change a variable so you could use it in a model?

Tags: statistics, regression

> If you had a variable where the functional form was incorrect and
>   unknown (not squared, or exponential, or square root, etc.), what
>   would be one way to “fix” the variable so you could use it in the
>   model?

Using linear regression I am not sure exactly what methods can be done. I know about BoxCox and some of the transformations but this is not something that we have learned so I do not believe it to be a relevant answer.

Comment: Can you plot $y$ against $x$?

Comment: @V.Vancak I assume we can. We have been given no data. This is more of a theoretical scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall Taylor Expansion of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$, i.e., 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k,
$$
asssuming that the data-generating model is $y_i = f(x_i)+\epsilon_i$ you can approximate $f(x_i)$ by a polynomial function. E.g.,
$$
\mathbb{E}[y_i|x_i] \approx f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2.
$$
You can use methods of variable selection to determine the most appropriate order, however if you don't have "enough" data points then you you should be careful to avoid over-fitting. In order to choose between linear and quadratic approximation you can apply, for example, Ramsey's RESET test.

Comment: It turns out the answer they were looking for was to make the data categorical (ie. factor)